# Open with lightbox when clicking on a div

Tags: css, lightbox

Is there any way to open an image with lightbox when clicking on a div that has as a background that image?

Thank you in advanced

Edited:

I have a div like this

```
<div id="image" background:url("path_image")></div>
```

What I want is that when I click over that div it could be displayed in a lightbox modal.

Comment: You'll need to post some of your code if you want someone to help you find a solution.

Comment: @DavidAlsbright I have posted some code

Comment: @Levimatt buddy, that's not some code!! its of no use to others.

Comment: I just have a div with a background image. I just want to know if it is possible to open the background image inside a lightbox modal

Comment: What @DeepakYadav means is that you should post the entire code part where your code is being used, instead of just this `<div id="image" background:url("path_image")></div>`

Comment: It's a trial I'm doing with a blank html page <html><body><div id="image" background:url("path_image")></div></body></html>. The path image is in the same folder as the html page. Could I use lightbox to open the background image in a modal lightbox or may I create a custom jquery/css to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. No problem.

Putting an anchor containing that div and using the lightbox normally it can be done.

Thank you all